# Can't build Node Module Screenres

Tags: node.js, module

the module in question allows changing of screen resolution:
https://github.com/davidmarkclements/screenres

It has support for mac and linux, I have written my own code for windows, that I would like to include. Writing and testing the code from command line without node has worked fine.

I'm trying to build on Windows 7 64bit and I am running into errors just building the source without my additions.

node-gyp configure works
node-gyp build fails and the module nan seems to be the culprit

```
I:\GitHub\screenres\node_modules\nan\nan.h(326): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan
::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPersistent(const v8::Local<T> &)': function template ha
s already been defined (compiling source file ..\screenres.cc) [I:\GitHub\scree
nres\build\screenres.vcxproj]
  I:\GitHub\screenres\node_modules\nan\nan.h(319): note: see declaration of 'Na
  n::imp::NanEnsureHandleOrPersistent' (compiling source file ..\screenres.cc)
I:\GitHub\screenres\node_modules\nan\nan.h(346): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> Nan
::imp::NanEnsureLocal(const v8::Local<T> &)': function template has already bee
n defined (compiling source file ..\screenres.cc) [I:\GitHub\screenres\build\sc
reenres.vcxproj]
  I:\GitHub\screenres\node_modules\nan\nan.h(334): note: see declaration of 'Na
  n::imp::NanEnsureLocal' (compiling source file ..\screenres.cc)
I:\GitHub\screenres\node_modules\nan\nan.h(374): warning C4996: 'v8::Isolate::I
dleNotification': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\screenres.c
c) [I:\GitHub\screenres\build\screenres.vcxproj]
  c:\users\marcgfx\.node-gyp\8.9.4\include\node\v8.h(7429): note: see declarati
  on of 'v8::Isolate::IdleNotification' (compiling source file ..\screenres.cc)
I:\GitHub\screenres\node_modules\nan\nan.h(560): error C2039: 'GCEpilogueCallba
ck': is not a member of 'v8::Isolate' (compiling source file ..\screenres.cc) [
I:\GitHub\screenres\build\screenres.vcxproj]
```

I've installed missing dependencies:

```
I:\GitHub\screenres>npm list
screenres@1.0.2 I:\GitHub\screenres
+-- bindings@1.3.0
+-- minimist@1.2.0
`-- nan@1.9.0
```

Maybe the code is just completely outdated? I would appreciate it, if someone found the time to try the provided code from the git repository.

Answer (score 0):

turns out pretty much everything seems to be outdated that this library was using. I was successful by kicking all references to other libraries and rewriting a lot of code. I ended up making something pretty different, so I might start a new github project.